# How to use Java 9 ObjectInputFilter size constraints?

Tags: java, deserialization, java-9

Java 9 has added some deserialization security measures to `ObjectInputStreams`, which in addition to the more widely used measures such as white/black lists for classes, also adds some size constraints: `arrayLength`​, `depth`​, `references​`, `streamBytes​`.

Array length and depth are straightforward, but how would you use properly use `references`? The documentation says: `The current number of object references`, but where are those references stored? It is not the number of references currently in the InputStream. If I send a one time use instance through the stream and no longer need it, I would expect the number to go down again, at the very least when it is garbage collected. I realize ObjectStreams maintain a `HandleTable`, where instances and their references are stored by default, but even when this is circumvented by using `readUnshared/writeUnshared` the problem remains. From my testing I've never seen the reference count ever going down (the same goes for `streamBytes`).

In case this number really does not ever go down, how would you handle an application that continuously sends data? Even if you were able to send everything `unshared` such that you could track when objects are finalized, how would you determine the `streamBytes` of that object?

Example:

```
ObjectInputStream in; // e.g. get from a socket
in.setObjectInputFilter(new ObjectInputFilter() {
    public Status checkInput(FilterInfo fi) {
        if (fi.references() > 1000) return Status.REJECTED;
        return Status.UNDECIDED;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would the number go down? How would the `ObjectInputStream` know whether you keep the objects around? It's a simple counter of deserialized objects. To know whether an object has been garbage collected, it would have had to maintain a `WeakReference` to every deserialized object, and then check them all to get that count. Way overkill if not needed, so `ObjectInputStream` doesn't do that, but maybe that is what you need to do yourself.

Comment: The number going down would make more sense from a user perspective, because otherwise you'd need to start with a low limit and continuously keep increasing it, so long as there is also a continuous stream of data coming in. Waiting for garbage collection doesn't really work as far as I know, because all objects are kept in the HandleTable of the ObjectInputStream, thus never collected. There may have been a mechanism to release objects from the HandleTable, but it doesn't seem like it, except to maybe use reset() on the stream, which has other complications.

Comment: Actually, the documentation of [`setObjectInputFilter​`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#setObjectInputFilter-java.io.ObjectInputFilter-) says *"The number of references is the **cumulative** number of objects and references to objects already read from the stream including the current object being read"*. I doubt that the functionality is intended for *continuous* streaming, so the number going down doesn't make any sense, and it would certainly go against the documented behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the question, `ObjectInputStream` maintains references to read objects (with the exception of those coming through `readUnshared`, through suitable `serialPersistentFields`, or similar). Data so far unread in the stream may have a backreference to any one of these objects (even if no other reference exists, so `WeakReference` is a red herring).

Continuous streaming objects without a reset ***is*** a leak.

I guess what the option is making an stab at mitigating is a stream using little data to create a huge number of objects, though I'm guessing there is a reasonable*ish* linear factor between data size and number of objects (unless something special is going on).